# I am looking for some advice on motor/motor controller?

Tags: motor-controller, component-selection

I am planning to create a rig to check my wheel speed probes. I am going to mount a gear and rotate it with an appropriate motor/motor controller.

Unfortunately I don't have much experience selecting motors. I have a 35V DC/25V AC power pack but don't know whether to select an AC/DC motor with a controller or use a potentiometer.

If I can vary the speed that would be great. Any advice on models of motor would be great.

Comment: (1) What's a "wheel speed probe". (2) Is this just a functional check. (3) Do you require accurate speed control? How accurate? (4) What motor speeds do you require?

Comment: A logical assumption is it's a probe that is put onto the wheel to get its RPM?

Answer (score 1):

At the voltage level mentioned and the power level that seems likely, you will likely find a larger selection of DC motors and controllers at a lower price compared to AC motors.

A potentiometer connected as a variable resistor is a possibility, but you may have a difficult time finding a suitable resistance and power rating to work with the motor. Also the speed stability and repeatability of setting could be a problem.

The best alternative will probably be a DC motor with an electronic speed controller. You will need to search to find out what is available with the required power and speed range.

If you want to pay the price, you can probably find an industrial product with extremely accurate speed control and a built-in speed display. Something like that would connect to utility AC power.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to take  an industrial servo drive. It wwould always come with all required software, tools and whatever you may need. The cost may be a little high... But wasted time is minimal